# Custom Icon, uploaded using custom image feature for quick links tile layout not displaying as intended

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages, quick-links

When uploading our branded custom icons to the quick links web part, which is in the tile display, using the "custom image" option, the icons are very faint and almost blurred. I have tried to scale them to a larger size. I have converted the files to SVG format. Nothing works. The built-in icons look and display normally, but my icons do not. Please advise on a solution.

I have added a screenshot below. the one on the left (policies) is our custom icon. The one on the right (jobs) is the built-in icon:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using images with below aspect ratios as per the layout you are using in Quick Links web part.

The Quick links web part has six different layouts. Here are recommended aspect ratios:

- Filmstrip, Grid, Button: `16:9`
- Compact, List, **Tiles**: `1:1`, `4:3`

**Source - Microsoft Documentation**: [Image sizing and scaling in SharePoint modern pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/image-sizing-and-scaling-in-sharepoint-modern-pages-dc510065-b5a5-4654-bc94-e3ecbbb57d8d)